# AngularJs popup datepicker won't open

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

My code is too large to post here, so I just post the relevant parts.

I have a fairly large app and now I want to add a datapicker. I copied the code from [the Angular UI bootstrap site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

In my controller I initialize

```
$scope.popup1 ={'opened': false}
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

and declare

```
$scope.open1 = function()
{
    $scope.popup1.opened=true;
}
```

and, in my view I have

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"   
   is-open="popup1.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"  
   datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"  
   ng-required="true" close-text="Close"   
   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">  
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

when I click the button, the function is called and `$scope.popup1.opened` is set to true.

However, the datepicker does not pop up.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to enable the datepicker or something?

Comment: when you just set true, is-open=true does it load opened?

Comment: A very good question!  But, alas, no, it does not :-(

Comment: @Mawg.. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: I am using a framework and was told that the datepicker was not compatible with the version of Angular which it used (so why was it released?). I have promised that an updated version will be emailed to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once that a calendar popup didn't show up. It turned out to just be a CSS problem, it was hidden behind another object. See if you can find the popup anywhere in the DOM and then check what it's z-index CSS property is set to.

Comment: An excellent suggestion (thanks, +1). I will check that when I get home this evening and let you know.

Comment: No, I do not see a datepicker in the DOM, just the input field, for showing the date/manaul entry of the date, and the button which should cause it to pop up